# permanence or maintenance

Tags: word-choice

What form is the most correct?

This justifies the permanence of the candidate in the current institution

or

This justifies the maintenance of the candidate in the current institution

Is there any suitable alternative?

Comment: Did you look either up in a dictionary? Also please visit http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Perhaps you want "this justifies the *continuance* of the candidate...?"

Comment: The choice and possible alternative depends on what you intend to say in the first place. Decide what you want to say, then maybe, come back and ask.

Comment: @Autoresponder Your handle can confuse people :) why not add a few digits somewhere?

Comment: Hi mplungjan thanks for the tip. I didn´t know about a version for english learners. Thanks for the suggestion Autoresponder.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are correct in the sense that they are grammatical and convey meaning. The most appropriate choice between the two words would entirely depend on what you want to say. Here are some basic dictionary definitions to get you started. If neither of these perfectly match your intended meaning then I suggest using a thesaurus.

> permanence — permanent condition: existence in the same form forever or for a very long time
>
> maintenance — continuing repair work: work that is done regularly to keep a machine, building, or piece of equipment in good condition and working order